# How to add onclick dynamically in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
 obj2 = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i <= obj2.length - 1; i++) {

            var row = table.insertRow(1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);

            cell1.innerHTML = obj2[i].qid;
            cell2.innerHTML = obj2[i].question;
            cell3.innerHTML = obj2[i].answer1;
            cell4.innerHTML = obj2[i].answer2;
            cell5.innerHTML = obj2[i].answer3;
            cell6.innerHTML = obj2[i].answer4;
           $(function(){
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        
                var t = document.createTextNode("Delete "+cell1.innerHTML); //this works well     
                btn.appendChild(t);   
                btn.className="menu_buttons";
                $(btn).on('click' ,function(){
                    delete_(cell1.innerHTML);//this assigns the value of the last iteration to each button


                });
                cell8.appendChild(btn);
            });
            }
```

I'm iterating over a json array and I want to assign the same function (with different parameter, depending on an id from the array) to each button, and as I mentioned in the comment, it overwrites each button with the same parameter. 
What's wrong?

Comment: I posted the whole loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Dynamic button , and attach event handler like this

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS

```
for(i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
     var test = $('<button/>',
    {
        text: 'D.Button',
        click: function () { alert('test'); }
    });
     $('#test').append(test);
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/pv8dmyn3/)**

Comment: I know yours is just an example, but we should *not* create functions inside a loop, also invoking a jQuery selector inside a loop is a bad idea. Here's a better and performant way: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/pv8dmyn3/3/